# Is there a way to break down a templated pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Currently I have a template like so:

```
template<typename func, typename ret, typename... args> class Entry{
public:
    PVOID Address;
    ret operator()(args...){
        return ((func) this->Address)(args...);
    }
};
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
Entry<int(*)(int), int, int> func;
//    ^func        ^ret ^args
func.Address = (PVOID) 0xDEADC0DE;
func(123); // calls 0xDEADC0DE with '123' as argument
```

However, I was wondering if it's possible to only have this:

```
Entry<int(*)(int)> func;
//    ^only specifying the function's prototype once instead of breaking it down
func(123);
```

If I have it like that, I wouldn't be able to overload `operator()` as I cannot split up the function pointer type into arguments and return type (so that I can write `return_type operator()(args...)`).

Is there any way to achieve this?

I'm using VS2013 Nov 2013 CTP

Comment: I thought there was a technical issue with storing function pointers in `void*`?  Certainly not on any platform VS2013 targets, I'd admit.

Comment: @Yakk, could be due to the size of function pointers (which may be way bigger than a normal pointer), but I'm not doing `&function`, I'm rather taking the address from the exports table and casting it, which shouldn't do any harm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a specialization like this:

```
// Entry has one template argument
template<typename func> class Entry;

// and if it's a function type, this specialization is used as best fit.
template<typename ret, typename... args> class Entry<ret(args...)>{
public:
  PVOID Address;
  ret operator()(args... a){
    return ((ret(*)(args...)) this->Address)(a...);
  }
};

int main() {
  Entry<int(int)> foo;
  foo.Address = (PVOID) 0xdeadc0de;
  func(123);
}
```

To use it with a function pointer type like in your example (although I like the function type syntax better), write

```
//                                            here ------v
template<typename ret, typename... args> class Entry<ret(*)(args...)>{
```

Addendum: One more thing came to me when I was out getting dinner: There is a (slight) problem with the `operator()` that may or may not concern you: You don't run into forwarding problems with parameters that are passed by value or by lvalue reference because they're just passed on as they were passed in (because the argument list is exactly the same for the function pointer and the `operator()`), but if you plan to use rvalue-reference parameters, that does not work for them implicitly. For this reason,

```
Entry<int(int&&)> foo;
foo(123);
```

does not compile. If you plan to use this with functions that take rvalue references, `operator()` can be fixed like so:

```
ret operator()(args... a){
  //                   explicit forwarding ----v
  return ((ret(*)(args...)) this->Address)(std::forward<args>(a)...);
}
```

Comment: Can I specify a calling convention with this? Like `Entry<int(__stdcall*)(int)> foo;` AND with the type syntax? Or I must use a function pointer?

Comment: You can use `Entry<int __stdcall(int)> foo;` with MSVC 2013. `__stdcall` is not part of the standard, so other compilers will probably not support it, though.

Comment: Amazing. Now, I tried adding a constructor to my class like this: `Entry<int __stdcall(int)> foo(0xC0DE);`, but it says `incomplete type is not allowed`. I'm using the type syntax. What am I missing?

Comment: A constructor could look like this: `Entry(std::uintptr_t addr) : Address((PVOID) addr) { }` (written into the specialization; `#include <cstdint>` for `std::uintptr_t`). What you wrote looks like a constructor call, not the constructor, and since I don't know how you wrote your constructor, I can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: that was my fault, I declared the constructor inside the second specialization. I now moved everything *except* the `operator()()` overload inside the first, one-parameter specialization, and the overload in the second one. Let's hope it works now! Thank you.

Comment: @AcidShout there should be nothing within the primary specialization.  It should be empty.  It should consist of `template<class Sig> class Entry;` -- no body, no contents, no code.  All code should be inside the `template<class R, class... Args> class Entry< R(Args...) >` specialization (or equivalent).

Comment: @Yakk, yeah, something was going wrong, had to find out the hard way. However, now I understand the two `<expressions like this>`, and I did it properly as you say, so it's compiling and working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Partial specialization as shown in @Wintermutes post is possible.
However, what you're trying should be possible without it:

```
template <typename func>
class Entry{
public:
    PVOID Address;

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
     -> decltype( ((func*) Address)(std::forward<Args>(args)...) ) {
        return    ((func*) Address)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

The template argument must be a function type. However, you can make it work with both function and pointer to function types with a slight modification in the return expression: Instead of using `func*` as the target type of the cast, use `typename std::remove_pointer<func>::type*`, i.e.

```
template <typename... Args>
auto operator()(Args&&... args)
 -> decltype( ((typename std::remove_pointer<func>::type*) Address)(std::forward<Args>(args)...) ) {
    return    ((typename std::remove_pointer<func>::type*) Address)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ffcf197aa232737).

Answer (score 0):

A metaprogramming approach.  First, some pointer traits that try to preserve calling convention information:

```
template<class...>types {using type=types;};
enum class calling_convention {
  cdecl,
  clrcall,
  stdcall,
  fastcall,
  thiscall,
  vectorcall,
};
template<class Sig>
struct signature_properties;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct signature_properties {
  using return_type = R;
  using argument_types = types<Args...>;
};     
template<class FuncPtr>
struct function_properties;
#define CAT_(A,B) A##B
#define CAT(A,B) CAT_(A,B)

#define CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT( CONVENTION ) \
  template<class R, class... Args> \
  struct function_properties< R(CAT(__, CONVENTION) *)(Args...) >: \
    signature_properties<R(Args...)> \
  { \
    using type = R(CAT(__, CONVENTION) *)(Args...) \
    static const calling_convention convention = calling_convention::CONVENTION; \
    static type from_pvoid(void const* pvoid) { \
      return static_cast<type>(pvoid); \
    } \
  }
CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT(cdecl);
CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT(clrcall);
CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT(stdcall);
CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT(fastcall);
CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT(thiscall);
CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT(vectorcall);
#undef CAT
#undef CAT_
#undef CALLING_CONVENTION_SUPPORT
```

Icky macros.  And serious overkill.  And untested.  But you get the idea.

Next, a helper to do the work:

```
template<class FuncPtrType, class R, class Args>
struct helper;
template<class FuncPtrType, class R, class... Args>
struct helper<FuncPtrType, R, types<Args...>> {
  FuncPtrType ptr;
  R operator()(Args...args)const {
    return ptr(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  helper(FuncPtrType p):ptr(p) {};
  helper( helper const& )=default;
  helper& operator=( helper const& )=default;
};
```

Perfect forwarding in the helper would also be tempting.

Finally, we use the traits class above to bounce the work from `Entry` to `helper`:

```
template<class FuncPtrType>
struct Entry:helper<
  FuncPtrType,
  typename signature_properties<FuncPtrType>::return_type,
  typename signature_properties<FuncPtrTpye>::arguments
> {
  using parent = helper<
    FuncPtrType,
    typename signature_properties<FuncPtrType>::return_type,
    typename signature_properties<FuncPtrTpye>::arguments
  >;
  Entry(void const* pvoid):parent( static_cast<FuncPtrType>(pvoid) ) {}
};
```

except we include a constructor in `Entry` to take a `void const*` and forward the typed pointer to `helper`.

One change is that we cast from `void*` to our function type at the earliest point we know it is the function type, rather than at the point we call.